# cdvphotolibrary: display on IONIC 4

Tags: ionic4

Is there a way to display cdvphotolibrary:// in Ionic 4?

I have tried most of the thing available out there to display the thumbanil:

```
<allow-intent href="cdvphotolibrary:*" />
<allow-navigation href="cdvphotolibrary://*" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="cdvphotolibrary:">
```

The idea is to display  such content, thumbnail in fact returned by the photolibrary:

```
cdvphotolibrary://thumbnail?photoId=43%3B%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDCIM%2FCamera%2F20190304_204426.jpg&width=512&height=384&quality=0.8
```

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-photo-library

Thanks

Comment: got any error?? and also you can make photo library looks using ionic columns and modal.

Comment: I'm getting the UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME when trying to render the thumbnail in DOM. I'm passing something like this : `<img src="cdvphotolibrary://thumbnail?photoId=1603%3B%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDCIM%2FCamera%2F20190813_170010.jpg&width=512&height=384&quality=0.8">`

Answer (score 1):

OK that error code has given up lots more info.

[It seems](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/54#issuecomment-364422747) that the `cdvphotolibrary://` protocol is classed as a `file://` protocol and you cannot use them with the newer webview.

There is, however, a workaround for file:// protocol:

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/webview#file-protocol

Which is:

> For Cordova apps, the Ionic Web View plugin provides a utility function for converting File URIs: window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(). There is also a corresponding Ionic Native plugin: @ionic-native/ionic-webview.

And also it seems that the file:// urls [are actually available](https://github.com/terikon/cordova-plugin-photo-library/issues/150#issuecomment-471326804) through the plugin:

```
    this.photoLibrary
      .requestAuthorization()
      .then(() => {
        this.photoLibrary
          .getLibrary()
          .subscribe({
            next: library => {
              library.forEach(libraryItem => {
                let url: string;
                if (libraryItem.id.split(';').length > 0) {
                  url = 'file://' + libraryItem.id.split(';')[1];
                }
                // Get http://localhost url
                url = (window as any).Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(url)
              });
            },
            error: err => {
              console.log('could not get photos');
            },
            complete: () => {
              console.log('done getting photos');
              console.log(this.images);
              count = 0;
            },
          });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("permissions weren't granted");
      });
```

However it seems like maybe there is some additional tweaking to do for Ionic - check out that thread to see the further discussion.

Comment: Thanks a lot man for answer. I did all you have mentioned above and my level is more than OK. But i still can't make it work for `cdvphotolibrary://` protocol:(
I get all the images, thumbnails and so on, but when it comes to use it in DOM, i get the UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME, as you mentioned above, it is something related to protocol. @rtpHarry

Comment: What i'm trying to render on UI is :`<img src="cdvphotolibrary://thumbnail?photoId=1603%3B%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDCIM%2FCamera%2F20190813_170010.jpg&width=512&height=384&quality=0.8">`

Comment: Rewrote my answer. :)

Comment: man, thanks for your research, but to let you know that the question is about getting "thumbnails" and not the native fileURI. I don't have any issues to display the file:// with the very heavy picture, i was looking for a solution for thumbnails, not the file.

Comment: @rtpHarry can we use options to add on videos in this getLibrary i'm not able to add option here